# How can I represent map[string][]byte?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I would like to create a map, but I am unsure of the syntax. The  `map[string][]byte` data type is giving me trouble, because I think that the example below should be what it should look like in order to appease the compiler, but I receive an error which is unclear about how it should be properly depicted.

```
map["k1":[1,2,3] "k2":[4,5,6] "k3":[7,8,9]]
```

The error message:

> expected type, found "k1"

How can I fix the syntax?

Comment: You're not using the correct syntax for [map literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals); try, you likely meant `map[string][]int{"k1":[1,2,3] "k2":[4,5,6] "k3":[7,8,9]]}` or perhaps `map[string][3]int{"k1":[1,2,3] "k2":[4,5,6] "k3":[7,8,9]]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bad syntax.
You should initialize it and declare like below

```golang
    x := map[string][]byte{
        "k1": []byte{1, 2, 3},
        "k2": []byte{4, 5, 6},
        "k3": []byte{7, 8, 9},
    }
```